Suppose that the eigenvalue of largest magnetude of $P$ is simple. Is it true that the the same happens to $U P$ for any unitary matrix $U$?
Suppose that $P = [p_{i,j}]_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that:

$p_{i,j}\geq 0$ for all $i,j\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\};$
$\sum_{j=1}^n p_{i,j}=1$;
$P$ is a symmetric matrix, $p_{i,j}=p_{j,i};$ and
$1$ is the unique eigenvalue in the peripheral spectrum of $P$, $i.e.$ if $\lambda\neq 1$ is an eigenvalue of $P$, then $|\lambda|<1.$

I am trying to prove or finding a counter-example to the following question:

Question: Let $U$ be an $n\times n$ complex unitary matrix. Define $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb C$ the eigenvalues of $U P$. Is it true that there exists a unique $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that
$$|\lambda_i| > \max_{j\neq i}|\lambda_j|? $$
In other words, is the eigenvalue of the largest magnitude of $U P$ simple?

I believe that the above statement should be true (even without assuming $P$ to be a probability matrix) because unitary matrices are essentially "rotations", so the eigenvalues norms should be preserved. However, I have not been able to show this, even supposing $U$ as a unitary diagonal matrix. Can anyone help me?

It's not true. Try the $2 \times 2$ case
$$ P = \pmatrix{5/8 & 3/8\cr 3/8 & 5/8\cr},\ U = \pmatrix{4/5 & 3/5\cr -3/5 & 4/5\cr} $$
where $U P = \pmatrix{29/40 & 27/40\cr -3/40 & 11/40\cr}$ has a double eigenvalue $1/2$.
[EDIT] If you want an example where $U$ is diagonal, try the same $P$ with
$$ U = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & \frac{7+24 i}{25}\cr}$$

Amazing counter example. Thx!

Just a quick question, please do not feel pressure to answer. Do you think that if $U$ is diagonal and unitary it is possible to find a counter-example?
